# Create a SQL report that treats an Aggregate expressions's solution and the result of a subquery as different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bit of an odd question here. We use Lansweeper for our IT help desk here, and its reports are built using sql. We're also able to do charts using those reports. My boss is requesting a chart that shows the progression of our computer replacements for the year. The idea I came up with is a pie chart that that gradually fills as computers get replaced. The two pieces data I'm using are:

- A count function that counts the number of computers that are due to be replaced this FY (The Count(tblAssets.AssetID) function where tblAssetCustom.Custom1 = '20')
- A Subquery that takes the original number of computers that were due this year (115) and subtracts the counted number from above, which gives us the total number of computers that have been replaced.

So at the start of the year, the first number would take up the entire chart, and the second number would be set to 0 (115-115). As computers with a replacement year of 20 gets removed from the system, the first number will tick down and the second number will tick up. My code is shown below:

```
Select Top 1000000 Count(tblAssets.AssetID) As [Computers to be Replaced],
 (Select 115 - Count(tblAssets.AssetID) As [Computers Replaced]) As
 [Computers Replaced]
From tblAssets
 Inner Join tblAssetCustom On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetCustom.AssetID
 Inner Join tsysAssetTypes On tsysAssetTypes.AssetType = tblAssets.Assettype
 Inner Join tblAssetGroupLink On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetGroupLink.AssetID
 Inner Join tblAssetGroups On tblAssetGroups.AssetGroupID =
   tblAssetGroupLink.AssetGroupID
Where tblAssetCustom.Custom1 = '20' And tblAssetCustom.State = 1 And
 tblAssetGroups.AssetGroup = 'Computers'
Group By tblAssetCustom.Custom1
```

I'm so close to getting it to work... I was able to get the report to give me the numbers I need to use, but I need to figure out how to format the report so Lansweeper can create the chart. [My report is coming out like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXt2O.png)

I don't even know for sure if this is possible (I'm not a coder, and have barely and surprisingly limped through getting it this far), but I need to figure out how to get my column names as entries in one column and my numbers into another column. Once I can get my data into separate rows, then the chart functionality will work. Is any of this possible? Anyone have thoughts or suggestions on how to approach this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the two values to be on separate rows, you can use your existing query as a `CTE` and then use a `UNION` to get the values individually:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    Select Count(tblAssets.AssetID) As [Computers to be Replaced],
     115 - Count(tblAssets.AssetID) As [Computers Replaced]
    From tblAssets
     Inner Join tblAssetCustom On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetCustom.AssetID
     Inner Join tsysAssetTypes On tsysAssetTypes.AssetType = tblAssets.Assettype
     Inner Join tblAssetGroupLink On tblAssets.AssetID = tblAssetGroupLink.AssetID
     Inner Join tblAssetGroups On tblAssetGroups.AssetGroupID =
       tblAssetGroupLink.AssetGroupID
    Where tblAssetCustom.Custom1 = '20' And tblAssetCustom.State = 1 And
     tblAssetGroups.AssetGroup = 'Computers'
    Group By tblAssetCustom.Custom1
)
SELECT 'Computers to be Replaced' AS name, [Computers to be Replaced] AS value
FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Computers Replaced', [Computers Replaced]
FROM CTE
ORDER BY name DESC
```

Output will look something like

```
name                        value
Computers to be Replaced    53
Computers Replaced          62
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the suggestion- your output is exactly what I'm trying to get. I tried entering your code into the system, and the report editor is balking at at the first SELECT. Unfortunately, nothing useful... "Invalid "SELECT" statement. Unexpected token "SELECT" at line 14, pos 1." Was there some tweaking I needed to do to the code, or something else I'm missing? Thanks for your help with this!

Comment: @tlonde sorry - I just realised I accidentally put a `,` on the end of the `CTE`. I've edited the answer.

Comment: No worries! The last time I got that error, it was because I was missing a comma after a Select statement, so that's what I was looking for and assumed your comma was correct! We're so close to getting there... had to add a column name back inside the CTE and I had to remove the ORDER BY command because it was throwing an error. However... while no additional errors were found inside the editor, I tried to run the report and got the message, "Error: Incorrect syntax near ')'."... which is super specific. As near as I can tell, everything near the closed brackets is correct

Comment: @tlonde yes, sorry, I had removed the `As [Computers Replaced]` because I didn't notice you were using that as a subquery, but there's no need for it to be a subquery anyway. The error you're getting is because you have no `FROM` in that subquery, if you just remove the subquery as I have done in my latest edit it should work...

Comment: Morning @Nick. Just got back to the office to try it, and still no luck... still getting "Error: Incorrect syntax near ')'. " I took the code from the CTE and ran that on its own, so that piece seems to be happy. So the hangup seems to be somewhere in the Union. I'll do some digging around as well to see if anything jumps out to me. Thanks for your continued help!

Comment: @tlonde what version of SQL server are you running? The query parses fine in all versions from 2012 on... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=3334d0e1eed8ba5caea1301b8cf7763a

Comment: SQL Server 2017. That is really frustrating. I wonder if it's Lansweeper that's being stupid? Still run into issues with the Order By clause... says its invalid unless Top, Offset, or For XML is specified. I add in Top 10000 statements for the last 2 Selects, but then it claims that "name" is an invalid column name. When I remove the Order By statement and run the report is where I'm hitting the syntax error.

Comment: Looks like it is something with Lansweeper.... I jumped onto the SQL server and figured out how to run the report against the database... and it behaved exactly as it was supposed to. I appreciate you taking the time to help me work through this, and hopefully I can figure out how to make Lansweeper cooperate. Thanks!

Comment: @tlonde sorry - I don't know how I can help any more. I've even tried the query in SQL Server 2017 with some [sample data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2e1aab01d3026ba4625daca1abf1a6b4) and it produces the expected results. But based on the Order by error you're seeing, perhaps Lansweeper is wrapping this in a view or a cte? in which case maybe [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1533c4cd9d9aa5ce2c95026f782905a8) might work?